# Fill in the missing values in one table by using a column in another table - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table (df1) that contains 3 columns - id, Industry, Job. I also have a table 2 (df2), which contains some of the values that are missing from df1.

```
DF1:
ID | Industry | Job
1    Tech       Data Engineer
2    N/A        N/A
3    Blah       Blah
4    N/A        Police Officer
8    Transport  N/A

DF2:
ID | Industry | Job
1    Tech       Data Engineer
2    Oil        Engineer
4    Government Police Officer
10   E-Sports   Gamer
```

I want to transfer the values that are missing in df1 from df2. Note that I DO NOT want to fully replace any values that are in df1 already and I only want to take values from df2 if they are missing in df1. Also note that ID 8 is missing in DF2, so I would want to keep the N/A in df1.

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: See [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). Just need to set the index first.